# Find the intersection between the following two curves in 3 unknown variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

There are two curves:
$$S1: xy^2z - yz + 2xz =39$$
and 
$$S2: 2x - 3y + 5z = 26$$

I tried substituting x, y, z into both equations alternatively to get an equation in two variables and then find the dependence of one variable on another. But, I am not able to get the solution.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank You.

I am able to substitute for x, y, and z, and as in this answer: [Find the intersection between the following two curves in 3 unknown variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856587/find-the-intersection-between-the-following-two-curves-in-3-unknown-variables/2856610#2856610), I even get that equation, but from here I am having a problem.

Comment: The method you described should work... Share your solution so we can take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: From the first erquation we get
$$z=\frac{39}{xy^2+2x-y}$$
plugging this in the second equation we obtain

$$2x^2y^2-3xy^3-26xy^2+4x^2-8xy+3y^2-52x+26y+195=0$$
this can be solved for $$x$$ or $$y$$

$$x^2(2y^2+4)+x(-3y^3+26y^2-8y-52)+3y^2+26y+195=0$$
Can you solve this?

Comment: You should of course consider the case that your denominator vanishes separately ;-)

Comment: Oh yes this should belong to my hint, thank you!

Comment: I am able to get this, but from here, I am having problems reducing.

Comment: You can solve the equation above for $x$ or $y$, $x$ is the better choice, since it is a quadratic equation.